# How to list dates of week in dropdown flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to list out the dates in dropdown from today and till the 7 days. How can I achieve that in Flutter?
Check the code below and the dates: right now I'm taking in an array list and sending to backend using some logic. How can I insert dates in the dropdown instead of the array list?

**View Dropdown Code:**

```dart
// Time Slot
restController.restaurant.scheduleOrder ? Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL, horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
  child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [

    Text('delivery_time'.tr, style: robotoMedium),
    SizedBox(height: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),

    Row(children: [
      Expanded(child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).cardColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.RADIUS_SMALL),
          border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor)),
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: AppConstants.preferenceDays[orderController.selectedDateSlot],
          items: AppConstants.preferenceDays.map((String items) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items.tr));
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value){
            orderController.updateDateSlot(AppConstants.preferenceDays.indexOf(value));
          },
          isExpanded: true,
          underline: SizedBox(),
        ),
      )),
      SizedBox(width: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
```

**Checking Value:**

```dart
if(orderController.timeSlots == null || orderController.timeSlots.length == 0) {
    _isAvailable = false;
}else {
    DateTime _date = orderController.selectedDateSlot == 0 ? DateTime.now() : orderController.selectedDateSlot == 1 ? DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)) : orderController.selectedDateSlot == 2 ? DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2)) : DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7));
    DateTime _startTime = orderController.timeSlots[orderController.selectedTimeSlot].startTime;
    DateTime _endTime = orderController.timeSlots[orderController.selectedTimeSlot].endTime;
```

**Array List:**

```dart
static List<String> preferenceDays = ['today', 'tomorrow', 'day_after_tomorrow', 'after_a_week'];
```

I want to change it to the Dates DropDown. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  items: preferenceDays.map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (_) {},
)
```

Comment: No you didn't got my question properly then please read the query again.